# SonarQube Integration with Eclipse: Associate with SonarQube option not working for simple java project

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

I am trying to integrate sonarqube with eclipse to analyse simple java project.
But it is not happing. When we right click on simple java project and hit Configure-> Associate SonarQube, the window appear where field appear like Project and SonarQube project.
Project field is autopopulated with the java project you right clicked and What we need to enter in SonarQube project is not clear to me. Also no tab is appearing where we can do something like SonarQube -> Analyse.
(I have added sonaqqube plugin in eclipse and also set sonarqube server path to localhost:9000)
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SonarQube Eclipse plugin lets you associate (and locally analyze) projects that have already been analyzed by other means (maven target, ant task, SonarQube runner). It is not meant as a way to launch persisted (shared) analyses.

So if you want to use the SonarQube Eclipse integration, please do a first analysis of your project, then try to associate it from Eclipse. This will allow you to synchronize the issues and perform local (preview) analyses.

[EDIT]
On recent (4.x) versions of SonarQube, you also have the option to provision your project on the server. This will allow you to associate your Eclipse project and perform preview analyses.

Comment: So a simple java project say a desktop application in java can't be analysed using sonarqube. It need to be a maven project or ant/gradle build one.

Comment: That's not what I said, for a simple Java project you can use the SonarQube standalone runner. But you have to create the project on the server before associating it to Eclipse.